# Chrome Redirects When Migrating From Single Page Website

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a somewhat unique circumstance in the fact that I formerly had a single page website... so for example previous navigation to the services page was: www.sixhatsolutions#services

My single page site was getting way to slow as I had too much on a single page so I now am in the process of migrating back to a normal site. When I launched the new site I noticed that it would not navigate to several of the pages... I examined and re-examined my code over and over again. It looked fine... Moreover it worked fine locally but server deployment seemed to break navigation.

In troubleshooting I manually entered in the url into the browser... and bam! It navigated back to the home page... so it wasn't my code after all. I thought it was something wrong with the server some wierd kind of redirect. So I gave them a call... and they couldn't figure it out either. So we are both on the phone trying to figure this thing out when I decide to open up IE and see if that works and sure enough IE navigated just fine...

Long story short After trying several other browser we discovered that it was just Chrome that was having the issue. After I thought about it I think it's the fact that Chrome is redirecting due to browser history. In other words my new page www.sixhatsolutions.com/services.html is beign sent back to www.sixhatsolutions#services.

Clearing out the browsing history resolves this redirect issue. My concern is the fact that the support rep that I spoke to was having the same redirect as me... and as far as I know he never visited by site. I can't ask all of my customers and potential customers to clear their browsing history just so they can navigate through my site!

My question is how can I fix this so that Chrome clears it history for all visitors? Or will this issue be resolved automatically when my site is re-indexed?

Comment: I don't see the problem visiting in Chrome so this may be a cache issue but not an issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a cache issue. There are ways to force the browser to clear the cache. How to do that seems to be answered here: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).